# Repeater Attributes

Tags: attributes, array

I am trying to create an attribute which can be repeated any number of times for a page. I am wondering how I can implement something like this with Magento attributes.

For example on the page there would be a text box and an add another button and on the template I could get an array of the lines of text submitted.

Comment: For which entity (product, page, etc.)?

Comment: How would these values be used? Would they need to be filtered or sorted on?

Comment: no just displayed on screen as links. would be an icon, a link, and text determined by three associated fields for each link and on screen a list of links one after the other.

Comment: Attributes in Magento are always associated with an entity. Which entity? Or are these just content blocks which will show in any context?

Comment: missed the first question about which entity. for a product.
In this case products may have 0..* links associated with them and I wanted to use attributes to fill in values for the link(text, destination, css class etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an attribute having a textarea for its frontend input and then a custom frontend model for rendering which would read the linebreaks as a value delimiter.